Make Load More With Javascript Fetch in Laravel
Can u guys help me how to create load more with my javascript
and this is my javascript for fetch API resource
<script type="text/javascript">
  const filterProduct = document.getElementById("filterProducts");
  const domain = window.location.host
  if (filterProduct) {
    // Fetch JSON data and generate HTML
    fetch(`http://api.${domain}/v2/categories`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        const generateCTGameHTML = (games, targetElementId) => {
          const gameListHTML = games
            .map(
              (game) => `
                <a class="group relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-murky-700 duration-300 ease-in-out hover:shadow-2xl hover:ring-2 hover:ring-primary-500 hover:ring-offset-2 hover:ring-offset-murky-900" href="order/${game?.slug}" style="outline: none;">
                  <img alt="${game?.title}" width="192" height="288" class="aspect-[4/6] object-cover object-center" src="${game?.image}" style="color: transparent;">
                  <article class="absolute inset-x-0 -bottom-10 z-10 flex transform flex-col px-3 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:bottom-3 sm:px-4 group-hover:sm:bottom-4">
                    <h2 class="truncate text-sm font-semibold text-murky-200 sm:text-base">${game?.title}</h2>
                    <p class="truncate text-xxs text-murky-400 sm:text-xs">${game?.production}</p>
                  </article>
                  <div class="absolute inset-0 transform bg-gradient-to-t from-transparent transition-all duration-300 group-hover:from-murky-900"></div>
                </a>
              `
            )
            .join("");

          const gameListElement = document.getElementById(targetElementId);
          gameListElement.innerHTML = gameListHTML;
        };
        data.forEach(function(cat){
            generateCTGameHTML(cat.lists, cat.panel);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error:", error));
  }
    // Drawer Menu
    function drawerMenu() {
      return {
          open: false,
          usedKeyboard: false,
          init() {
              this.$watch('open', value => {
                  value && this.$refs.closeButton.focus()
                  this.toggleOverlay()
              })
              this.toggleOverlay()
          },
          toggleOverlay() {
              document.body.classList[this.open ? 'add' : 'remove']('h-screen', 'overflow-hidden')
          }
      }
  }

</script>

this my html
 <div id="filterProducts">
            @foreach ($typecategories as $item)
                <div class="hidden" id="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}panel" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}panel-tab">
                <div id="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-4 sm:gap-x-6 sm:gap-y-8 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-6"></div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
          </div>

in my html code not add a button from load more because i dont know how to called in javascript system,
and i need load more form diferent panels like my json

This my json form API


[
    {
        "_id": "B0AACBFC143915E51DA0",
        "panel": "TopUps",
        "lists": [
            {
                "_id": "4D9D082AA579BC083B91",
                "title": "Mobile Legend",
                "production": "Moonton",
                "slug": "mobile-legend",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/B2C0EEDC2F7F3F3FED99.webp"
            },
            {
                "_id": "9DBEA3A115CFCBF0588F",
                "title": "Call Of Dutty",
                "production": "Garena",
                "slug": "call-of-dutty",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/DAD584AD18173A577DB8.webp"
            },
            {
                "_id": "262C4C5EE1E3155FD336",
                "title": "Free Fire",
                "production": "Garena",
                "slug": "free-fire",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/2EA149D36A8F45505FD1.webp"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "352426BF7F7B9A697148",
        "panel": "Voucher",
        "lists": [
            {
                "_id": "9AAB33BCF8405239AAC9",
                "title": "TESTING KATEGORI",
                "production": "TESTING",
                "slug": "testing-kategori",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/729B1BF05BC9F54A2696.webp"
            },
            {
                "_id": "AFCF4BCE0B7FE85B3578",
                "title": "asdsda",
                "production": "asdasdasd",
                "slug": "asdsda",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/642AF002249DEDF5DD91.webp"
            },
            {
                "_id": "DD890C5739C94F809296",
                "title": "asddassda",
                "production": "sdaasdsda",
                "slug": "asddassda",
                "image": "http:\/\/api.bjtopupku.test\/storage\/categories\/C7F9F5CBD230FB7D27F2.webp"
            }
        ]
    }
]




Modify your HTML to include a "Load More" button for each panel
<div id="filterProducts">
    @foreach ($typecategories as $item)
        <div class="hidden" id="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}panel" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}panel-tab">
            <div id="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}" class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-4 sm:gap-x-6 sm:gap-y-8 lg:grid-cols-5 xl:grid-cols-6"></div>
            <button class="load-more-button" data-panel-id="{{ preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $item->name) }}">Load More</button>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

Next, modify your JavaScript to handle the "Load More" button click event and fetch additional data:
const filterProduct = document.getElementById("filterProducts");
const domain = window.location.host;

if (filterProduct) {
    const fetchGames = async (panelId) => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://api.${domain}/v2/categories/${panelId}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data.lists;
    };

    const generateCTGameHTML = (games, targetElementId) => {
        const gameListHTML = games
            .map(
                (game) => `
                    <a class="group relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-murky-700 duration-300 ease-in-out hover:shadow-2xl hover:ring-2 hover:ring-primary-500 hover:ring-offset-2 hover:ring-offset-murky-900" href="order/${game?.slug}" style="outline: none;">
                        <img alt="${game?.title}" width="192" height="288" class="aspect-[4/6] object-cover object-center" src="${game?.image}" style="color: transparent;">
                        <article class="absolute inset-x-0 -bottom-10 z-10 flex transform flex-col px-3 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out group-hover:bottom-3 sm:px-4 group-hover:sm:bottom-4">
                            <h2 class="truncate text-sm font-semibold text-murky-200 sm:text-base">${game?.title}</h2>
                            <p class="truncate text-xxs text-murky-400 sm:text-xs">${game?.production}</p>
                        </article>
                        <div class="absolute inset-0 transform bg-gradient-to-t from-transparent transition-all duration-300 group-hover:from-murky-900"></div>
                    </a>
                `
            )
            .join("");

        const gameListElement = document.getElementById(targetElementId);
        gameListElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', gameListHTML);
    };

    filterProduct.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('load-more-button')) {
            const panelId = event.target.dataset.panelId;
            const games = await fetchGames(panelId);
            generateCTGameHTML(games, panelId);
        }
    });

    // Initial loading of games
    document.querySelectorAll('.load-more-button').forEach(async (button) => {
        const panelId = button.dataset.panelId;
        const games = await fetchGames(panelId);
        generateCTGameHTML(games, panelId);
    });
}

Let me know if that helps. Thanks
